# Why is Erza able to feel pain during Kyouka's fight?

Tags: fairy-tail

> **Don't read the question below if you are not up-to-date to the Fairy Tail manga. It may contain spoilers**

In the chapter 399-400 from Fairy Tail manga, Erza is fighting Kyouka to stop faces's activation.

During this fight, Kyouka used her curse to increase Erza's sensitivity to pain.

[image]

After this curse, she used another one to remove all Erza's five senses. But Erza continued to fight.

[image]
[image]

One of the five senses is **tactile perception**. Without it, she should not be able to feel anything, including pain. Shouldn't it make Kyouka's first curse useless?

But somehow Erza continued feeling a lot of pain and suffering a lot.

[image]

How can she feel this amplified pain since all her senses were stolen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sense#Non-traditional_senses), pain **isn't** one of the *traditional senses*. It's marked under *non-traditional senses*.

I think that's the reason pain is NOT stolen together with tactile perception (well, I thought, before I looked deeper, pain is connected to the *touch* sense, but it seems not).

Traditional senses:

1. Sight
2. Hearing
3. Taste
4. Smell
5. Touch

These are 5 base senses (for more info, view [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_wits#The_.22outward.22_wits)). As you can see, *pain* **is not** listed. But there are others like:

1. Balance and acceleration
2. Temperature
3. Kinesthetic sense
4. **Pain**
5. Other internal senses

As you write,

> she can curse to increase Erza's sensitivity to pain

but then

> she remove all 5 senses from her in **other curse**.

Pain is not a base sense.

Comment: If you could clarify your answer a bit more it would be pretty good ;)

Comment: Check my edit, Pain is not in 5 senses.

Comment: Looks allot better already, good job :)

Comment: I once had "surgery" on my toe to remove a really bad ingrown toenail. They numbed me up good by injecting stuff directly onto my 4 main nerves, but still said i would experience Pressure, but no pain. Turns out they missed one and it hurt like hell, so they went back in and got it. From then on, I felt every move as they trimmed the nail all the way back to the root, but i didn't feel any real pain, just phantom pain because the pressure was so intense. +1 from me, I had it in real life but in reverse.